# Keep div's from pushing each other

Tags: css

The picture is the layout  that I want but when you hover, everything gets messed up. The div's start shifting around and moving horizontally when the next div italicizes. How can I maintain this exact layout 100% of the time?
[image]

```
.project-link {
font-family: 'UtopiaStd';   
color:#010202;
font-size:5.6vw;
white-space:nowrap;
text-decoration:none;
margin-right: 3%;
line-height:125%;
border-bottom: solid transparent 2px; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zjkouzbo/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1:

You had the right idea with trying `white-space:nowrap`. To keep your first two links together and keep them on one line, wrap them in a parent element and apply the `white-space:nowrap` to that *parent* element. If you have that on both the anchor elements and the parent elements, then you won't break the lines in the middle of a link or between them.

```
<div class="line">
  <a class="project-link" id="one" href="#modal1">Maru speaker design <span> (1) </span> </a>
  <a class="project-link" id="two" href="#modal2">Lights — Out  <span> (2) </span></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.line{
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

New fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zjkouzbo/2/

Solution 2:

Place a non-breaking space between the anchor elements that you want to keep on the same line using the HTML entity `&nbsp;`. Just make sure that you take out any other spaces, including line breaks, between the two elements. This makes your code a little annoying to read, but it doesn't suffer from the "div-itis" that solution one does.

```
<a class="project-link" id="one" href="#modal1">Maru speaker design <span> (1) </span> </a>&nbsp;<a class="project-link" id="two" href="#modal2">Lights — Out  <span> (2) </span></a>
```

Second fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zjkouzbo/3/

Comment: Thanks! That second way works perfectly. Just a side question, is the reason that the words sort of shift when you hover over the left items because the width of italicized words are smaller than those of regular words? How can I make the width of italicized words keep the same width as when they're not italicized ?

Comment: Yes, changing to an italic style is essentially the same as any other font change. The letters have different forms, and the width will change. The best way to deal with this would be to create a couple of classes for the anchor elements on the left and fix their width to whatever works. For example, .long{display:inline-block; width:50vw;}

Answer (score 1):

Since the `<a>` tag is an inline element, it will adjust which 'line' it is on as the parent block element changes width, or in your case the link width changes size. If you want to keep a the particular layout where link 1 and 2 are on the same line, but different lines from the rest, you should organize each group in a block element.

```
<div class="project_miniwrap">
<div class="group-block">
  <a>Link 1</a>
  <a>Link 2</a>
</div>
<div class="group-block">
  <a>Link 3</a>
  <a>Link 4</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

adding

```
display:inline-block
```

and removing the line breaks you added to project-link solves the issue.

https://jsfiddle.net/70dceskq/1/